# IE7 float text around image inside floated div

Tags: css, css-float, internet-explorer-7

Working on simply floating text around an image, but it's not going well in IE7. The text is pushed below the image, as if no float.

From what I've read, the reason for this could be that the image and text are within a floated (and fixed width/height) div, which presumably triggers "hasLayout" for the containing div. I've been looking for a clean workaround, but none has yet been found.

In worst case I guess I can use jQuery, as I am already using that on the page, but I would prefer to solve this with CSS.

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2VbGq/), works well in good browsers, but should fail in IE7.

Good (Firefox, Safari, Chrome, Opera, IE8+):

[image: Good image]

Bad (IE7):

[image: Bad image]

HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="box_section">
        <div id="container1">
            <div id="container2">
                <div class="box">
                    <img src="http://c69282.r82.cf3.rackcdn.com/robot.jpg"/>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum etc etc whatever.</p>
                </div>

                <div class="box">
                    <img src="http://c69282.r82.cf3.rackcdn.com/pushing278.jpg"/>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum etc etc whatever.</p>
                </div>                    
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
/* Container for floating boxes */
#box_section
{
    height: 300px;  /* Fixed height and width */
    width: 984px;
    margin-top: 35px;  
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;  
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;    
}

/* Containers used to centre floated items independent of number */
/* In real webpage there can be any number of boxes. */
#container1
{
  padding: 0;
  float:left;
  width:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
}

#container2
{
  clear:left;
  float:left;
  padding:0;
  position:relative;
  left:50%; 
}

/* The box. OMG. */
.box
{  
  float: left;  
  position:relative;
  right:50%;
  height: 190px;            /* Note fixed height and width */
  width: 350px;
  border-style: solid;  
  border-color: #ebead4; 
  border-width: 1px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  margin: 20px;  
  overflow: hidden;  
}

/* Goal is to float text around image. Note that images have fixed width/height.
Images snatched from random website for demonstration purposes. */
.box img
{
  float: left;
  margin-right: 15px;
  height: 180px;
  width: 200px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-color: #eeeeff; 
  border-width: 1px;
}
```

Note that the solution for the containing div must be quite flexible, as there can be any number of these boxes and they have to be floated in the center (jQuery is used to only display one row at a time). The boxes can also be any one of 4 different fixed widths.

Also this is further complicated by the fact that the image can be one of 2 widths (2 different CSS classes), or not be there at all. I thought about making the image position absolute and do it with margins, but that therefore fails.

Comment: Worki ng fine in IE7 for me strangely. I'd suggest removing the position: relative on .box asit doesn't seem to be required and also consider adding a css reset file or at leeast declaring "* {margin:0;padding:0;}"

Comment: Oh, sorry, I have "* {margin:0;padding:0;}". About the position relative, that is just a remnant from me trying to fix this with absolute positioning of the image. Sorry. Not sure why it works for you in IE7, but I have not tried the fiddle in IE7 as compatibility mode for IE9 doesn't allow me (and that's the oldest IE I have).

Comment: Do you have a valid doctype declared in your page?

Comment: @Billy Just html, I'm using html5 and a shiv. And actually I found that position: relative was necesarry for the centering of the boxes to work (in any browser, apparently)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aw scrap it. My mistake.

Turns out the fiddle works fine in IE7, and the problem was that I had a global css rule for "header" elements which set min-width. I used header elements in my boxes... Feeling very smart now.

Thanks to all of you who tried to help.

Answer (score 1):

Add this code into you CSS

```
.box p{
    float:left;
     width: 130px;    
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2VbGq/1/

Comment: That did not appear to work.. Also, note that the image does not have to be there and that the box can be one of 4 sizes. I would probably need to add logic with jQuery to set that width.

Comment: But IE7 is morally old browser)),  
that's enough to support it

Comment: Well, it's probably lighter to write a jQuery function than adding a new library since we're talking about a single issue. I don't get your first comment, what do you mean?

Comment: You can add this library inside IF_IE condition of HTML document

Comment: I could, but it would be lighter to just write a jQuery function, no? Still, I'd like to do this with CSS if possible.

Comment: You could have more problems in IE7, but this js library save your time

Comment: You are right about that, so I tried the library, but it does not solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.... remove "P" tag for content any image is floated to left hope this will work...